# Are these objects we found ambergris? How to distinguish ambergris from other deposits/minerals

Tags: zoology, botany

These two objects below were found on the East Coast of the North Island of New Zealand on seperate occasions but within 5km of each other.

They both had a strong and unique, neither pleasant nor displeasing scent to them which has since faded.

The larger of the two is slowly shedding/crumbling small white clumps, presumably as it continues to dry up, a little lump of a resin like material has also become dislodged. The smaller of the larger two lumps has stayed fully intact.

**Are they [ambergris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambergris)?**

How can an amateur determine if they are or not? What else could they be?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is unlikely to be ambergris. As I understand it, ambergris tends to darken with age and be a waxy substance with a low (~60 C/140 F) melting temperature. and should melt a little in your hands to give a waxy feel. The smell should be animal- or fecal-like.

Your last image shows a crystalline substance with obvious fracture planes, which means that it is some sort of solid.

I think this is almost certainly the resin from a species of [coniferous tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conifer). As you are on the East Coast of the North Island, it could well be pieces of *[Agathis australis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agathis_australis) (Kauri) [gum/resin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kauri_gum), especially so if you are in Northland or the Coromandel. Kauri are only found about as far south as the bottom of the Coromandel/Kaimai range in the East and down to around Kawhia in the West.

If it is Kauri gum, it will be hard and have a pinetree-like scent, especially when scratched. You should also be able to polish it with turpentine. Kauri gum is semi-fossilized and a form of amber.

Auckland Museum has some pieces of Kauri gum that resemble what you have, and you can find this image on Wikimedia Commons:

[image: Kauri gum]

<sup>Auckland Museum, CC BY 4.0 https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0, via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Or this one from [Te Ara](https://teara.govt.nz/en) (The Encyclopedia of New Zealand):

[image: Te Ara Kauri gum]

Comment: Interesting, I shall gently warm some up and see what happens 

Comment: I don't have very good temperature control, but it does melt under a heated knife. However I read that kauri gum also readily melts ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯